# Fetching USER_ID of all the users in an organization of Google Workspace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I need to find USER_ID of all the users in our current organization. We have Google Workspace - Basic plan and have 120+ users.

Please refer here for what USER_ID I'm talking about
https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#messages_that_mention_specific_users

What is the easiest way to fetch the USER_ID? The solution can be something like where Google Sheet is updated with the new user and its USER_ID.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

*It is not possible to get this `USER_ID` of all the users in a specific domain. This is what the documentation says about this `id`:*

> To determine the USER_ID for a user, examine the sender field of the incoming message from the user.

*Also, if you were to use the [space.members.list](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list) method to get a [membership](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members#Membership) (or a [user](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/User)) resource, they do not contain any `id`.*

### Work around

There is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users) in the documentation that shows how to get all the users in a Google Workspace domain. I have modified it to get the user ids and finally create a `Sheet` with all the information.

### Code

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  var userList = []
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        userList.push([user.id, user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail])
        Logger.log('u:%s, %s (%s)', user.id, user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  var nusers = userList.length
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('usersList')
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,nusers,3).setValues(userList)
  console.log(ss.getUrl())

}
```

### References

- [Admin SDK Directory Service: List all users](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users)
- [Chat API: Method spaces.members.list](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list)
- [Chat API: Resource Membership](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members#Membership)
- [Chat API: Resource User](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/User)